# Adding an Attribute to CSS class Selector in C#

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I have a css class selector like this:

```
.somecssclass
{
}
.somecssclass:after
{
    border-left: 2px solid #ff0000;
}
```

I know I can add a cssclass to a control by doing something like this:

```
pnl.CssClass = "somecssclass";
```

But is it possible to dynamically add an attribute to that class selector of that control?

Answer (score 0):

Well not exactly but you can create a new `css-calss` and add that to same control. A control can have multiple `css-clasees`

```
pnl.Attributes.Add("class", "some-class")
```

---

You can add a particular attribute to the control as follow

```
pnl.Style.Add("float", "left");
```

**Note** that it will add an inline css in on the control.

Comment: Sure. but the thing is I have to add the attribute to the cssclass selector only. Thanks for the reply anyway. But is there a way to add a cssclass selector rather than just cssclass

Comment: you can add a new css-attribute from code also. You comment is not clear.

Comment: I meant I wanted to add attribute to .cssclass:after{} rather than .cssClasss{} itself from codebehind.

Comment: you can add attributes to control only. not in the css file. If you want to change the file you need to use file handling.